# Pandas: Looping through a list of strings in a column & create a new column with string

Tags: string, pandas, for-loop

**Goal:** I would like to search through a column called "Profile Name" in my DF and whether part of the name contains a certain market. For example, if the "Profile Name" (XX - France - AM) contains "France", I would like to add the string "France" to a new column called "Markets" in the DF. Ideally, I want to use a loop to go through 5 different markets and apply the same logic (i.e. if "Profile Name" contains Italy, add Italy to "Markets".

I've tried many different versions to do this but this seems to be the closest:

```
markets = ['France','Spain','UK','Germany','Italy']
for name in markets:
    if df[df['Profile Name'].str.contains(name, na=False) == True]:
       df['Market'] = name
```

**It gives me this error:** ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Anyone has a suggestion on how I can do this best? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do all in one line:

```
df['Market'] = df['Profile Name'].str.extract(f'({"|".join(markets)})')
```

**Update**: run time comparison (`len(df) = 8000`).

```
%%timeit -n 100
df['Market'] = df['Profile Name'].str.extract(f'({"|".join(markets)})')
# 8.46 ms ± 151 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%%timeit -n 100
for name in markets:
    df.loc[df['Profile Name'].str.contains(name, na=False, regex=False), 'Market'] = name
# 16.7 ms ± 200 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: Regex vs sheer substring search may be slower. It would be interesting to check if this is penalized.

Comment: for a toy data, regex is faster than `contains` with looping. probably because you don't need to scan through all the string many times.

Comment: Seems legit. I guess, at least partially, in this we make use of the fact that we don't care what substring we found (or we're sure we can have only one single substring).

Answer (score 0):

Use pandas' .loc[] syntax:

```
markets = ['France','Spain','UK','Germany','Italy']
for name in markets:
    df.loc[df['Profile Name'].str.contains(name, na=False, regex=False), 'Market'] = name
```